# Insert multiple rows using the same foreign key that needs to be selected

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, insert

Assume that there are two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE products (id SERIAL, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE comments (id SERIAL, product_id INT, txt TEXT);
```

I would like to insert multiple comments for the same product. But I don't know the product_id yet, only the product name.

So I could do:

```
INSERT INTO comments (txt, product_id) VALUES
    ( 'cool', (SELECT id from products WHERE name='My product name') ),
    ( 'great', (SELECT id from products WHERE name='My product name') ),
    ...
    ( 'many comments later', (SELECT id from products WHERE name='My product name') );
```

I'd like to reduce the repetition. How to do this?

I tried this but it inserts no rows:

```
INSERT INTO
  comments (txt, product_id)
SELECT
  x.txt,
  p.id
FROM
  (
    VALUES
      ('Great product'),
      ('I love it'),
      ...
      ('another comment')
  ) x (txt)
  JOIN products p ON p.name = 'My product name';
```

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b1710f91d3c9488be1bed807851e7b0e What's your exact problem?

Comment: I would use a cross join though: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bb343f1ced092d481c834a3f2b2d811d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query works just fine. The only way it inserts zero rows is if there is no product in the table `products` for a given string - in your query named `My product name`. However, @a_horse_with_no_name's suggestion to use a [`CROSS JOIN`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cross-join/) might simplify your query a bit. You can combine it with a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-with.html) to collect all comments and then `CROSS JOIN` it with the record you filtered in from table products.

```
CREATE TABLE products (id SERIAL, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE comments (id SERIAL, product_id INT, txt TEXT);    
INSERT INTO products VALUES (1, 'My product name'),(2,'Another product name');

WITH j (txt) AS (
  VALUES ('Great product'),('I love it'),('another comment')
) 
INSERT INTO comments (product_id,txt)
SELECT id,j.txt FROM products
CROSS JOIN j WHERE name = 'My product name';

SELECT * FROM comments;  
 id | product_id |       txt       
----+------------+-----------------
  1 |          1 | Great product
  2 |          1 | I love it
  3 |          1 | another comment
```

Check this [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2b93f420f837681d46068e05f6f7cfa9)

Comment: Why did you use "Temporary" Table here? Or why is it necessary here? Sorry if this sounds basic. I am just a novice in SQL

Comment: @Priya I just used the temporary tables to keep my system clean, as they disappear once the session is over :-D It is definitely not necessary for the example